# Scrolling not working properly for nested scrollviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am facing similar problem mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437515/uiscrollview-inside-uiscrollview). But the solution which is given here is disabling and enabling outer scrollview when inner scrollview scrolls. This is working fine but it is not good to use outer scrollview form inner scrollview. It is making my code bad. Do anyone know how can i achieve this without using outer scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8307022/5654848). This is the swift version:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

var offset: CGPoint = scrollViewA.contentOffset() //or scrollViewB

}


func setContentOffset(contentOffset: CGPoint, animated: Bool) {

if scrollView == scrollViewA {
    // change offset of B
}
else {
    // change offset of A }
}

}
```

Comment: I don't have access to outer scrollview instance.

Comment: Is there any way by which i can block passing of swipe events from inner scrollview to outer scrollview.

Comment: What about de-nesting the scroll views? Instead of embedding a scrollview inside another scrollview, make them same-level siblings of a parent UIView. Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1852085/5654848) .

Comment: This can be done. But in my case i can't make them siblings. They have to be nested for some reason.